# Compile Failing for iOS 4 with Sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, compiler-errors

I wrote an iPhone app against SDK 2.2, I have updated my XCode and SDK so now I only have SDK 4.2 and I want to update my app to run with that.

The problem is I can't even get it to compile!

I get the following error:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h:5772: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'int'

The line in question is:

SQLITE_API int sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback(
  sqlite3 *db,
  const char *zGeom,
  int (*xGeom)(sqlite3_rtree_geometry *, int nCoord, double *aCoord, int *pRes),
  void *pContext
);

I have tried relinking the newer sqlite frameworks, both libsqlite3.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib, but both still cause this error.

If I comment out my import statement (#import "sqlite3.h"), it compiles just fine.  (Although it crashes when I run it, obviously.)

Comment: It sounds like SQLITE_INT is being defined to something that the compiler can't recognize. What do you see if you run `gcc` with the `-E` flag to see what the preprocessor is producing for the compiler to work with?

Comment: Running 'gcc -E' at the terminal gives me:  i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files.  I'm not sure if that was what you were asking for though.  If I need to add the -E flag somewhere in my project settings, I don't know where to do that.

Comment: I installed XCode 3.2.3 with iOS 4.0 SDK and my app compiles and runs just fine in iPhone Simulator 4.0.  But using the same project and opening it in XCode 3.2.5 with any simulator, it fails to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the same way Sqlite.h use to import this library:

```
   #import <sqlite3.h>
```

and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work after replacing #import "sqlite3.h" by #import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new project, and importing all the files from the original, and then linking the sqlite framework.  After that it compiled just fine.